# Prevent EditText from consuming the touches on it

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

i want to prevent the EditText from receiving the touch events on it in order to show the ripple effect behind it. here is the code sample: 
is there any way to do so?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:hint="Hint"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="24dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingBottomenter code here="24dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/field"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:inputType="none
                    tools:ignore="Autofill,LabelFor,TextFields" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add in your xml file these items:

```
android:enabled="false"
```

Is it what you mean under ripple effect?